# Measurability of the event that Brownian motion hits a given set

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W$
  be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ on a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$
 . Let us assume $\mathcal{F}$
  is the sigma-algebra on the path space $C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$
 .

I'm trying to prove that the set $\left((W_{t})_{t\geq0}\;\mathrm{hits}\; A\right)$
  is $\mathcal{F}$
 -measurable if $A$
  is a Borel measure set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

If $A$
  is open, then it is clear to me that only need to consider rationals, since $W$
  will have to enter $A$. Similarly, if it closed then it hits iff it get arbitrarily close, so rationals again suffice. But I'm not sure how to proceed for a general borel set.

Also, what if we do not know anything about $\mathcal{F}$
 . Can we then still get a conclusion?

And finally, is the event $\left((W_{t})_{t\geq0}\;\mathrm{hits}\; A\right)$
  measurable for more general sets than Borel measurable ones?

EDIT: I am aware of the so-called Debut Theorem about hitting times being stopping times (implying measurability), but I am looking for a more elementary proof of just the fact that the event is measurable.

Comment: Blumenthal and Getoor consider measurability of such hitting times in their book "Markov processes and Potential theory" (Chapter I.10) for general Markov processes. At least in this general case, the measurability is highly non-trivial.

Comment: @saz Thanks for the reference. However, I was thinking that there should be a more elementary proof if I don't necessarily want to prove that the hitting time is a stopping time, but only that the event is measurable.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it was just a side remark in case that you are interested in these kind of things.